# Error with mock RealmObject class

Tags: android-studio, realm, mockito

I can not understand how to use the classes of the model Realm when testing in Mockito. If the class is inherited from RealmObjec

```
public class Foo extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private String PK;

public Stuff getStuff(){
    return new Stuff();
}

public int getNum(){
    return 1;
}
}
```

Wrapping in mock for tests

```
@Test
public void clearObject(){
    Foo mock = mock(Foo.class);
}
```

And even if I wrap in spy

```
 @Test
public void SpyOnRealmObject(){
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Foo spy_foo = spy(foo);
}
```

Error when running tests:

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class ru.arvalon.coffeeorder.trash.Foo.

If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : JetBrains s.r.o
JVM vendor version : 25.152-b02
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows 8.1
OS version         : 6.3


You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inlined mocks.
You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.

Underlying exception : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [class java.lang.Object, class ru.arvalon.coffeeorder.trash.Foo, class io.realm.RealmObject, interface io.realm.RealmModel, interface io.realm.internal.ManagableObject]

at ru.arvalon.coffeeorder.mainpage.RealmCheck.RealmObject(RealmCheck.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...

Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [class java.lang.Object, class ru.arvalon.coffeeorder.trash.Foo, class io.realm.RealmObject, interface io.realm.RealmModel, interface io.realm.internal.ManagableObject]
at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138)
at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346)
at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161)
at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355)
... 28 more
```

Section in build.gradle did not help

```
android {
testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        jvmArgs '-noverify'
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please show build gradle for Mockito dependency and Realm version

Comment: project build.gradle:
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.0.0"
    }
app level build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
...
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.17.0'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}